# XGBoost and Random Forest lead to constant predictions on test set when training data are centered

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, r-caret, xgboost

I am doing omics data analysis and I have a 269x600 dataset that I splitted into training and test set (80-20). My variable to predict is the hippurate's concentration and has 4 different values (0, 75, 150, 300) but I am doing regression on it.

I ran both random forest and XGBoost using the `caret` infrastructure on the **centered training set**,  where I did cross-validation to select the optimal hyperparameters.
 The problem is that when I predict the test set using the selected models, I obtained (nearly) constant predictions. That is, a value of around 269 for the whole test set.

However, when I ran the same models but on the **non-centered training set**, the  predictions are very good, and these even outperform all my previous models.

My question is thus : 
**why the fact of only centering the training data leads to this weird result for both models ?**

I know these models do not require such preprocessing to work but I don't understand why it does not work if we preprocess, and here why the results change that much when we only center data ...

Comment: Did you also center the testing set variables using the same centering parameters used for the training set ?

Comment: @MarcoSandri Wow how I did'nt even think about that ? It worked very well when I centered the test set. However, I still don't really understand the issue... I did not center the test set either for other models such as *(stepwise) linear regression*, *elastic nets*, *(sparse or orthogonal) partial least squares*, *PCR* or *ICR*, ... and it gave results that seemed acceptable. But of course, the results now change for these models too when I predict on the centered test set ..... I did not think a simple location shift on the input features compared to the test set could have a so big impact

Answer (score 2):

Think about what you are doing by shifting the train vs test.

You are likely ensuring that every sample in your test set will be out of the range of the training data.

Thus your every feature in your test-data will effectively be all the same ( really high, or really low ) compared to the training data, and will end up in the same terminal nodes in the trained model.

And thus they will all yield the same prediction

This is proof that tree models ***do not extrapolate well***

```
require(xgboost)
X <- matrix(rnorm(10000, mean = 10),nrow = 100)
y <- sample(c(0,1) , 100, replace = T)

bst1 <- xgboost(data = X, label = y, nrounds = 20)

# gonna scale test and not train
# test predictions are the same
p <- predict(  bst1, newdata = scale(X))
> p
  [1] 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985
  [9] 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985
 [17] 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985
 [25] 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985
 [33] 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985
 [41] 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985
 [49] 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985
 [57] 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985
 [65] 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985
 [73] 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985
 [81] 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985
 [89] 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985
 [97] 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985 0.3643985
```