# Debugging RandomForestRegressor() producing mainly constant forecast results over time-series data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, random-forest

Let's say I have [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18PGLNnOI44LVFignYriBWQFW9WBkTX5c/view?usp=share_link) contains a timestamp (*non-standard* timestamp column without datetime format) as a single feature and `count` as Label/target to predict within the following [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) dataframe format as follows:

```
   X        y
Timestamp label
+--------+-----+
|TS_24hrs|count|
+--------+-----+
|0       |157  |
|1       |334  |
|2       |176  |
|3       |86   |
|4       |89   |
 ...      ...
|270     |192  |
|271     |196  |
|270     |251  |
|273     |138  |
+--------+-----+
274 rows × 2 columns
```

I have already implemented RF regression within [sklearn](/questions/tagged/sklearn) `pipeline()` after splitting data with the following strategy for 274 records:

> - split data into [*training-set* + *validation-set*] [Ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59452915/10452700) *e.g. The first 200 records [160 +40]*
> - keeping **unseen** [*test-set*] hold-on for final forecasting *e.g. The last 74 records (after 200th rows\event)*

```py
#print(train.shape)          #(160, 2)
#print(validation.shape)     #(40, 2)
#print(test.shape)           #(74, 2)
```

I tried default pipeline as well as optimized one by tuning Hyper-parameters to get optimum results by equipping the RF pipeline with [GridSearchCV()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/putting_together.html), however results didn't improve as follow:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

print(f"r2 (defaults): {r2_score(test['count'], rf_pipeline2.predict(X_test))}")
print(f"r2 (opt.):     {r2_score(test['count'], rf_pipeline2o.predict(X_test))}")

#r2 (defaults): 0.025314471951056405
#r2 (opt.):     0.07593841572721849
```

[image: img]

Full code for reproducing the example:

```py
# Load the time-series data as dataframe
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('/content/U2996_24hrs_.csv', sep=",")

# The first 200 records slice for training-set and validation-set
df200 = df[:200]          

# The rest records = 74 events (after 200th event) kept as hold-on unseen-set for forecasting
test = df[200:]   #test (keep it unseen)

# Split the data into training and testing sets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = df200[['TS_24hrs']]
y = df200['count']
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y , test_size=0.2, shuffle=False, random_state=0)  #train + validat
X_test = test['count'].values.reshape(-1,1)


# Train and fit the RF model
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
#rf_model = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=10).fit(train, train['count']) #X, y

# build an end-to-end pipeline, and supply the data into a regression model and train within pipeline. It avoids leaking the test\val-set into the train-set
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, make_pipeline

# Pipeline (defaults) 
rf_pipeline2  = Pipeline([('scaler', MinMaxScaler()),('RF', RandomForestRegressor(random_state=10))]).fit(X_train,y_train)   #Approach 2 train-set excludes label

# Pipeline (optimum)
# Parameters of pipelines can be set using '__' separated parameter names:
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit

tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits = 5)
param_grid = {
    "RF__n_estimators": [10, 50, 100],
    "RF__max_depth":    [1, 5, 10, 25],
    "RF__max_features": [*np.arange(0.1, 1.1, 0.1)],}

rf_pipeline2o = Pipeline([('scaler', MinMaxScaler()),('RF', GridSearchCV(rf_pipeline2,
                                                                         param_grid=param_grid,
                                                                         n_jobs=2,
                                                                         cv=tscv,
                                                                         refit=True))]).fit(X_train,y_train) #Approach 2 train-set excludes label

# Displaying a Pipeline with a Preprocessing Step and Regression
from sklearn import set_config
set_config(display="text")

#print(rf_pipeline2) 
#print(rf_pipeline2o)

# Use the pipeline to predict over the validation-set and test-set

y_predictions_test2  = rf_pipeline2.predict(X_test)
y_predictions_test2o = rf_pipeline2o.predict(X_test)

y_predictions_val2   = rf_pipeline2.predict(X_val)
y_predictions_val2o  = rf_pipeline2o.predict(X_val)

# Convert forecast result over the test-set into dataframe for plot issue with ease
df_pre_test_rf2  = pd.DataFrame({'TS_24hrs':test['TS_24hrs'],        'count_forecast_test':y_predictions_test2})
df_pre_test_rf2o = pd.DataFrame({'TS_24hrs':test['TS_24hrs'],        'count_forecast_test':y_predictions_test2o})


# Convert predict result over the validation-set into dataframe for plot issue with ease
df_pre_val_rf2  = pd.DataFrame({'TS_24hrs':X_val['TS_24hrs'],        'count_prediction_val':y_predictions_val2})
df_pre_val_rf2o = pd.DataFrame({'TS_24hrs':X_val['TS_24hrs'],        'count_prediction_val':y_predictions_val2o})

# evaluate performance with MAE
# Evaluate performance by calculate the loss and metric over unseen test-set
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_percentage_error, explained_variance_score, r2_score 

rf_mae_test2  = mean_absolute_error(test['count'],                 df_pre_test_rf2['count_forecast_test'])
rf_mae_test2o = mean_absolute_error(test['count'],                 df_pre_test_rf2o['count_forecast_test'])

#visulize forecast or prediction of RF pipleine
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots( figsize=(10,4))

pd.Series(y_train).plot(label='Training-set', c='b')
pd.Series(y_val).plot(label='Validation-set', linestyle=':', c='b')
test['count'].plot(label='Test-set (unseen)', c='cyan')

#predict plot over validation-set
df_pre_val_rf2['count_prediction_val'].plot(label=f'RF_predict_val (defaults)              ', linestyle='--', c='green',   marker="+")
df_pre_val_rf2o['count_prediction_val'].plot(label=f'RF_predict_val (opt.)       ', linestyle='--', c='purple',    marker="+", alpha= 0.4)

#forecast plot over test-set (unseen)
df_pre_test_rf2['count_forecast_test'].plot(label=f'RF_forecast_test (defaults)     MAE={rf_mae_test2:.2f}', linestyle='--', c='green',   marker="*")
df_pre_test_rf2o['count_forecast_test'].plot(label=f'RF_forecast_test (opt.)           MAE={rf_mae_test2o:.2f}', linestyle='--', c='purple',    marker="*", alpha= 0.4)

plt.legend()
plt.title('Plot of comparioson results of used implementation approaches trained RF pipeline ')
plt.ylabel('count', fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('Timestamp [24hrs]', fontsize=15)
plt.show()
```

I have implemented different approaches, but I have not figured out to debug the problem so far. In the past time, I had some issues with another regressor that outputs constant prediction, and I resolved them with Hyper-parameters tuning like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71285022/10452700).

Furthermore, based on this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/235233/240550):

> *"...**random forest** for regression / regression trees doesn't produce expected predictions for data points **beyond the scope of training data range** because they cannot extrapolate (well)."*

Despite this could explain constant forecast concerning **out-of-sample prediction** over test-set (unseen), but still, I believe that even if it is the case, it should show a non-constant prediction over the validation-set in my case while it is constant.

---

Some related posts:

- [Random Forest Regression: When Does It Fail and Why?](https://neptune.ai/blog/random-forest-regression-when-does-it-fail-and-why)
- [Why did the prediction results of Random Forest and Gradient Boosting change into a straight line after a certain time point?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74673426/10452700)
- [XGBoost and Random Forest lead to constant predictions on test set when training data are centered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44095921/10452700)
- [Forecasts are constant all the time in time series data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67625762/10452700)
- [LSTM Time-Series produces shifted forecast?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57927187/10452700)
- [Time series forecasting- wrong result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69495910/10452700)
- [facebook prophet produces constant forecasts for time series with less than 25 observations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57960616/10452700)
- [Time Series Forecasting Python | Constant Increasing Predictions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59617202/10452700)
- [Time Series Forecasting model with LSTM in Tensorflow predicts a constant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60000473/10452700)

Answer (score 0):

This is not unexpected at all. Given that your only input is a consecutive number, all of the predictions on the test set will roughly correspond to the last value of the training set as it will follow the same decision rule. You cannot do TS forecasting like this. Either use a model that handles TS data (ARIMA, LSTM) or transform the data in a way that the inputs to the model are the targets of previous K observations.

Comment: Thanks for your input. As you mentioned, I have noticed and used some approaches with k previous observations. Thus, I experimented with & equipped the RF model with lookback methods: `walk_forward_validation` (WFV) & `series_to_supervised` (STS) and got better results. I already posted another [question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/121127/69263); about the forecasting quality they lead and the possible differences between these two. Perhaps you want to check it out. But still, I can't convince myself why RF regressor has this constant prediction over validation-set and test-set.

Comment: Maybe I can give you an intuitive explanation about the  constant prediction. In sklearn the decision trees constructed using "less equal" operators for each split. Now imagine that your input (in the training set) is anumber from 1 to 100. So each decision rule will have a form “INPUT <= W” where W is a number also in the range (1, 100). In your validation and test sets the input to the model is the number > 100. So no matter what the actual split rules are, all the values will end up in the same leaf node as the last training sample.

Comment: Based on my findings and the limitation of RF I addressed in this post, I may convince myself of this RF output (out-of-sample prediction) over the unseen test-set but I couldn't figure out why it outputs constant prediction over validation set. but it is interesting you observed RF model predicts/repeats the **last observation** within the training data.

Comment: Based on the chart you attached to your question, there should not be much difference between test and val sets from the model's perspective as they both contain values from the future timesteps compared to the training set.

Comment: Short question based on your explanation, then why are they some non-constant forecasts over unseen test-set, unlike predictions over validation-set? So you mean RF perform the same for both validation-set and the unseen test-set. On other words, RF perform for both out-of-sample prediction (predicting beyond the training dataset) over future data? if it is the case, is the problem not the way I split the data or the bug in  `train_test_split()` for TS analytics? SInce you mentioned regardless of _....actual split rules are,..._ it performs constant over future data (validation/test-sets)

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use a more suitable model, like a model understanding periodicity e.g. a Gaussian process with the right kernels, or other models. You can also consider [skforcast](/questions/tagged/skforcast) or [sktime](/questions/tagged/sktime) as libraries more suitable for time series data.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I checked that impressive workaround [skforecast GitHub](https://github.com/JoaquinAmatRodrigo/skforecast/) and its *Time series transformation, including an exogenous variable*. I think the Lookback methods for k steps/observation (`walk_forward_validation` & `series_to_supervised`), which I tested and discussed in this [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/121127/69263), cover the point you mentioned.

Comment: Furthermore, I will compare the results soon using [skforecast](https://www.cienciadedatos.net/documentos/py27-time-series-forecasting-python-scikitlearn.html) package & [Skforecast](https://www.cienciadedatos.net/documentos/py27-time-series-forecasting-python-scikitlearn.html) approach.